# Changing ltspice export from cortesian to voltage values when using AC anlysis

Tags: ltspice, matlab

I'm trying to export a waveform from ltspice into an excel document to be later graphed using Matlab. I am simulating a simple series bandpass filter and when I export the voltage across a capacitor. It is not simply putting the voltage values into the second column. I am only given the option to use polar or Cartesian coordinates. Then when I am parsing the data in Matlab, it is not populating the variables because the second column is being occupies by coordinates. Can I change this export format somehow??

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is not what OP's after (and I misunderstood?), but it looks like he needs to add `.option meascplxfmt=cartesian` to the LTspice schematic prior to simulation. See the help for `LTspice > Dot Commands > .options` and look at `MEASCPLXFMT` for details. It allows three keywords: `bode`, `cartesian`, `polar`.

Comment: This helps me when viewing LTSpice Measurement in the SPICE Error Log, I'm expecting non-decibel measurement.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to, thats the beauty of scripting languages.

First generate a text file with Cartesian coords.
Use the importer to generate a script, like this:
[image] 
then add a loop to post process the text.

```
>> Vn002{1}

ans =

8.53289842950458e-002,-5.03255593977887e-006
```

This is what the first value of my array looks like, but its a cell with text, so to get it to numbers you use sscanf. (%f means you want to convert an string with floating point format to a number.)

```
temp = sscanf(Vn002{1},'%f,%f')
dB = temp(1);
phase = temp(2);
```

This is for one line, I hope your able to put this inside a loop.

Comment: How does this get me to just the voltage value? I have this in my Matlab script. % read in data from excel get frequency values
    freq = xlsread('data.xlsx','A2:A5002');
% 50 ohms 5000 Hz series
    [num1,Vn001] = xlsread('data.xlsx','B2:B5002');
    y1        = zeros(5001,1);
    for n = 1:5001
        y1(n) = sscanf(Vn001{n},'%f');
    end
I'm only getting the first coordinate but when I have '%f,%f' I keep getting errors and do not know how to resolve them besides doing what I have done above.

Comment: Can you convert from dB to voltage? \$ dB = 20 × log (V_{out} / V_{in}) \$ where Vin is your source

Comment: I am only able to get the first coordinate into my vector, would this still apply?

Comment: Don't use excel, use the data importer in matlab under TABS: Home-> Data import

Comment: I figured it out, thanks for your help though.

Comment: I'm trying to graph the phase data now. I add the phase graph and then remove the magnitude graph. When I export and get it into Matlab, it is using the magnitude information again. How do I export the phase information?

Comment: The phase and magnitude are both in the text file, there are three columns but only two variables because of the ' marks Exa: 'num1,num2' matlab imports it as text (or can depending on the options you select)

Comment: If you like the answer, then mark and upvote.

Comment: There are three columns but two of them are coordinates. I am taking the magnitude of the two coordinates and get the correct voltage waveform. Here is an example of what is in the text file 'Freq. V(n003)
1.00000000000000e+001 1.00000105141008e+000,-1.20450613831843e-004
1.00230523807790e+001 1.00000105626317e+000,-1.20728282339576e-004
1.00461579027840e+001 1.00000106113866e+000,-1.21006590991247e-004'